# PHP: Find statement in statement with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

currently i have the following situation: 
I'm trying to "parse" a text, looking for placeholders (their notation is "{...}") and later on, i will replace them with the actual text.

I thought about regular expressions

```
$foo = "Hello World {foo{bar}} World Hello!";
$bar = array();
preg_match_all('@\{.+\}@U', $foo, $bar);
var_dump($bar);
```

But this returns

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "{foo{bar}" } }
```

Making it greedy will result in:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "{foo{bar}}" } }
```

But i want the result to be something like:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "{bar}" [1]=> string(10) "{foo{bar}}" } }
```

Is there a way to reach this with the help of preg_match(_all) and regular expressions?

Or do i have to loop over my $bar again and again, until there are no sub-statements left in the result set?

Comment: How are you going to replace the text anyway? It would somehow made sense to iterate while there are placeholders to be found if you want to allow nested groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're lucky you have PCRE for this. This has to be solved using recursion: http://regex101.com/r/pO3hA0

`/(?=({(?>[^{}]|(?1))+}))/g` (you don't need the g flag in php)

Comment: Thank you for that!
Is there a "guarantee" that {bar} will always precede {foo{bar}} in the result array?

Comment: The engine will match from the "outside" and work its way in, if you will. So you _should_ get `[0] => {foo{bar}} [1] => {bar}`

Comment: Thanks, but i wrote a little function that will sort the results by "complexity" (counting the braces in the result...)